# Stored procedure is very slow

Tags: sql-server, optimization, stored-procedures

I'm not a database specialist and want to ask about issue I have.

There's MS SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure that is very slow. How does it work?

```
1) Stor. proc. takes 2 input parameters: beginDate and endDate (DATETIME)
2) The temporary table is created using: DECLARE @temp TABLE (columns)
3) INSERT INTO @temp SELECT columns FROM huge_view WHERE conditions1
4) INSERT INTO @temp SELECT columns FROM huge_view WHERE conditions2
5) SELECT columns FROM @temp GROUP BY columns ORDER BY columns
```

The huge_view has some INNER, LEFT and RIGHT JOINS.

I know it's hard to say something without taking a look at the real code, but maybe somebody could give some guidelines.

Comment: Ensure there's appropriate indexes in play (you can include indexes over the views as well as their underlying tables).  You may be able to improve performance by removing the temp table and simply doing a `union all` on the two selects (or if huge_view is the same view in both steps 3 and 4 you can simply do where (conditions1) or (conditions2) - though in that scenario any records which match both sets of conditions would only appear once instead of twice.

Comment: Is it slow when you run the same SQL code outside of the stored procedure, in Management Studio?

Comment: Do you know which of these steps is the most time-consuming? I would expect it to be one or both of the inserts; identifying the main source of the performance problem is the first step in fixing it.

Comment: be careful as you are using a variable table, not a true "temporary" table which starts with a "#". If your table is really huge, variable tables (@) are not well suited

Comment: Ok. First of all I'd like to know if the time indicator in right lower corner in status bar in SQL Server Management Studio is reliable to measure the execution time?

Comment: In general, yes. It will include the time to transfer the data as well as execution time. You can use the Client Statistics view/capture in SSMS to get the execution time. You should also be capturing the execution plan to see what the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the performance is slow when you run it on the SQL Server itself or is it slow when you execute it from a client machine. If it is slow only from client machine, network is the issue.
2. Check how much data the view has.
3. Check if the tables have Primary Key, foreign key and  constraints where ever applicable. They can dramatically increase the performance of the joins.
4. Run the Database Tuning advisor to find out what additional indexes and statistics you can create.

Comment: Executing the query by logging onto the server interactively should not be necessary. Capture the client statistics in SSMS and it will show the execution time (on the server) vs. total time. Logging onto the server interactively should almost never be required - nearly everything about SQL Server can be managed remotely.